# I am new to oracle but I am creating a procedure in a package in oracle and I get this Error Message Can anyone see what i am doing wrong?

Tags: oracle, plsql

"Error(33,13): PLS-00323: subprogram or cursor 'USP_CHECK_USER_ADMIN' is declared in a package specification and must be defined in the package body"

```
create or replace 
PACKAGE         PKG_CUST_XREF1 AS

PROCEDURE USP_ADD_CUSTOMER
(
   p_CUST_ID IN MDW.CUSTOMER_STRUCTURE_XREF.CUST_ID%TYPE
   , p_ADDR_SUF IN MDW.CUSTOMER_STRUCTURE_XREF.ADDR_SUF%TYPE
   , p_PLAN_SYS_ID_SOURCE_CD IN MDW.CUSTOMER_STRUCTURE_XREF.PLAN_SYS_ID_SOURCE_CD%TYPE
   , p_REGION_ID IN MDW.CUSTOMER_STRUCTURE_XREF.REGION_ID%TYPE
   , p_COMPANY_ID IN MDW.CUSTOMER_STRUCTURE_XREF.COMPANY_ID%TYPE
   , p_REP_ID IN MDW.CUSTOMER_STRUCTURE_XREF.REP_ID%TYPE
   , p_TYPE_ID IN MDW.CUSTOMER_STRUCTURE_XREF.TYPE_ID%TYPE
   , p_EXTERNAL_ACCT_NO IN MDW.CUSTOMER_STRUCTURE_XREF.EXTERNAL_ACCT_NO%TYPE
   , p_REGION_NAME IN MDW.CUSTOMER_STRUCTURE_XREF.REGION_NAME%TYPE
   , p_COMPANY_NAME IN MDW.CUSTOMER_STRUCTURE_XREF.COMPANY_NAME%TYPE
   , p_SUF_NAME IN MDW.CUSTOMER_STRUCTURE_XREF.SUF_NAME%TYPE
   , p_CUST_NAME IN MDW.CUSTOMER_STRUCTURE_XREF.CUST_NAME%TYPE
   , p_INDUSTRY_TYPE_DESC IN MDW.CUSTOMER_STRUCTURE_XREF.INDUSTRY_TYPE_DESC%TYPE
   , p_CHANNEL_TYPE_DESC IN MDW.CUSTOMER_STRUCTURE_XREF.CHANNEL_TYPE_DESC%TYPE
   , p_INDUSTRY_SPECIALIST_ID IN MDW.CUSTOMER_STRUCTURE_XREF.INDUSTRY_SPECIALIST_ID%TYPE
   , p_CUSTOMER_CLASS IN MDW.CUSTOMER_STRUCTURE_XREF.CUSTOMER_CLASS%TYPE
   , p_ORA_CUST_ID IN MDW.CUSTOMER_STRUCTURE_XREF.ORA_CUST_ID%TYPE
   , p_STATUS IN MDW.CUSTOMER_STRUCTURE_XREF.STATUS%TYPE
);
END PKG_CUST_XREF1;

/* BODY!!*/

create or replace 
PACKAGE BODY         PKG_CUST_XREF1
IS
PROCEDURE USP_ADD_CUSTOMER(
   p_CUST_ID IN MDW.CUSTOMER_STRUCTURE_XREF.CUST_ID%TYPE
   , p_ADDR_SUF IN MDW.CUSTOMER_STRUCTURE_XREF.ADDR_SUF%TYPE
   , p_PLAN_SYS_ID_SOURCE_CD IN MDW.CUSTOMER_STRUCTURE_XREF.PLAN_SYS_ID_SOURCE_CD%TYPE
   , p_REGION_ID IN MDW.CUSTOMER_STRUCTURE_XREF.REGION_ID%TYPE
   , p_COMPANY_ID IN MDW.CUSTOMER_STRUCTURE_XREF.COMPANY_ID%TYPE
   , p_REP_ID IN MDW.CUSTOMER_STRUCTURE_XREF.REP_ID%TYPE
   , p_TYPE_ID IN MDW.CUSTOMER_STRUCTURE_XREF.TYPE_ID%TYPE
   , p_EXTERNAL_ACCT_NO IN MDW.CUSTOMER_STRUCTURE_XREF.EXTERNAL_ACCT_NO%TYPE
   , p_REGION_NAME IN MDW.CUSTOMER_STRUCTURE_XREF.REGION_NAME%TYPE
   , p_COMPANY_NAME IN MDW.CUSTOMER_STRUCTURE_XREF.COMPANY_NAME%TYPE
   , p_SUF_NAME IN MDW.CUSTOMER_STRUCTURE_XREF.SUF_NAME%TYPE
   , p_CUST_NAME IN MDW.CUSTOMER_STRUCTURE_XREF.CUST_NAME%TYPE
   , p_INDUSTRY_TYPE_DESC IN MDW.CUSTOMER_STRUCTURE_XREF.INDUSTRY_TYPE_DESC%TYPE
   , p_CHANNEL_TYPE_DESC IN MDW.CUSTOMER_STRUCTURE_XREF.CHANNEL_TYPE_DESC%TYPE
   , p_INDUSTRY_SPECIALIST_ID IN MDW.CUSTOMER_STRUCTURE_XREF.INDUSTRY_SPECIALIST_ID%TYPE
   , p_CUSTOMER_CLASS IN MDW.CUSTOMER_STRUCTURE_XREF.CUSTOMER_CLASS%TYPE
   , p_ORA_CUST_ID IN MDW.CUSTOMER_STRUCTURE_XREF.ORA_CUST_ID%TYPE
   , p_STATUS IN MDW.CUSTOMER_STRUCTURE_XREF.STATUS%TYPE)
 IS

 BEGIN
   INSERT INTO MDW.CUSTOMER_STRUCTURE_XREF
   (
   CUST_ID
   , ADDR_SUF
   , PLAN_SYS_ID_SOURCE_CD
   , REGION_ID
   , COMPANY_ID
   , REP_ID
   , TYPE_ID
   , EXTERNAL_ACCT_NO
   , REGION_NAME
   , COMPANY_NAME
   , SUF_NAME
   , CUST_NAME
   , INDUSTRY_TYPE_DESC
   , CHANNEL_TYPE_DESC
   , INDUSTRY_SPECIALIST_ID
   , CUSTOMER_CLASS
   , ORA_CUST_ID
   , STATUS
    ) 
   VALUES (
   p_CUST_ID
   , p_ADDR_SUF
   , p_PLAN_SYS_ID_SOURCE_CD
   , p_REGION_ID
   , p_COMPANY_ID
   , p_REP_ID
   , p_TYPE_ID
   , p_EXTERNAL_ACCT_NO
   , p_REGION_NAME
   , p_COMPANY_NAME
   , p_SUF_NAME
   , p_CUST_NAME
   , p_INDUSTRY_TYPE_DESC
   , p_CHANNEL_TYPE_DESC
   , p_INDUSTRY_SPECIALIST_ID
   , p_CUSTOMER_CLASS
   , p_ORA_CUST_ID
   , p_STATUS);

  COMMIT;

END USP_ADD_CUSTOMER;

END PKG_CUST_XREF1;
```

Comment: I can't find the word USP_CHECK_USER_ADMIN in the example source. But it is relevant.

Comment: add the implementation of USP_CHECK_USER_ADMIN to the body (or remove it from the spec)

Comment: There isn't a `USP_CHECK_USER_ADMIN` in either the spec or the body, so there's no way to answer to the actual error message. In general, make sure the signatures (parameter names, parameter count, parameter type) all match. Also, if this is a single script you need a slash (`/`) after the package spec - say before the pointless `/* BODY!! */` comment.

Comment: The presence of the `COMMIT` in the package is generally bad form. The caller of the method should decide when to commit.

Comment: Perhaps the current version of the package spec compiled on the database still has the procedure USP_CHECK_USER_ADMIN; if it's not required, recompile your package spec before compiling your new package body.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can see what you're doing wrong - the PL/SQL compiler tells you the exact reason:

```
PLS-00323: subprogram or cursor 'USP_CHECK_USER_ADMIN' is declared in a package
specification and must be defined in the package body
```

If you have problems to understand the error message please see chapter *Package Body* from [PL/SQL Packages](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/packages.htm#i2416).

You probably should read the whole [Oracle Database PL/SQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/toc.htm) too.